# in java, use String::length for Comparator.comparing()

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a code piece like this:

```
String[] yetToSortedArray = {"Abc","hello world","nihao?","chilemaNin"};
Arrays.parallelSort(yetToSortedArray, Comparator.comparing(String::length));
for(String str : yetToSortedArray){
    System.out.println(str + ", ");
}
```

My question is here: "String::length" 
What am I really passing in to Comparator.comparing()? 
Why there is no parenthesis for String::length()?

I think I am using this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-

And it says "Accepts a function that extracts a Comparable sort key from a type T, and returns a Comparator that compares by that sort key."

How dos String::length match this type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String::length` is a [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Using it is equivalent to

```
Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length())
```

So it compares strings by comparing their length.

Comment: But it’s strongly recommended to use [`comparingInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) instead…

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR: You are passing a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Java 8 introduces lambda syntax to the Java language, this is a small part of that, it allows you to pass a *method* as a *lambda*.

So you call the method `Comparator.comparing`, this requires a "key extractor" function that takes an object from the `Collection<T>` and returns some object of a type `U extends Comparable<? super U>`.

The method `String.length` returns an `Integer` (when boxed) and an `Integer` is comparable to another `Integer`. So the call `Comparator.comparing(String::length)` returns a `Comparator<String>` that:

- takes a pair of `String`, `s1, s2`
- calls `l1 = s1.length` and `l2 = s2.length`
- returns `l1.compareTo(l2)`

**So, *Why there is no parenthesis?***

Because you are passing a method *reference*. This method will be called *later* on an as yet undefined instance. Notice that `length` is not `static` on `String` so `String.length()` would not compile.