# Sort array in Java with lambda function

Tags: java

Why did this lambda function work?

```
String[] months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","December"};

Arrays.sort(months,(String a, String b) -> a.length() - b.length());
```

Why it's `a.length() - b.length()`, not just based on a.length()?
Why does `Arrays.sort(months,(String a) -> a.length())` not work?;

Comment: Sorting requires a `Comparator`, which is a function that _compares_ two objects.  You can't sort on just `a.length` because that tells you nothing about how `a` is related to any other objects.  You can't tell from just the lengths whether `a` comes before or after `b`.  By using a `Comparator`, you're providing a way to indicate whether or not one object is "bigger" than another object, which allows you to sort them.

Comment: Sort functions return negative and positive values to determine whether an element comes before or after another. Using `a.length()` will always return a positive value, which wouldn't change the order. Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)

Comment: Look up the documentation for the two-arg version of `Arrays.sort()`.  Look at the type of the second argument (`java.util.Comparator`), and read that type's documentation, especially the documentation of its single non-default, non-static, non-inherited-from-`Object` method.  This is what the lambda needs to implement.

Answer (score 3):

The `(String a, String b) -> a.length() - b.length()` is the Single-Abstract-Method shortcut for [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and `Comparator`'s `compare` method must satisfy `compare(a, b) > 0` if and only if `compare(b, a) < 0`, otherwise it wouldn't define a proper comparison function. Such a function obviously cannot work if you discarded the argument `b` and returned an `int` based only on `a`. If you wanted to "sort-by" length, you could use `Comparator.comparing(String::length)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753525/in-java-use-stringlength-for-comparator-comparing)).